# Displaying UTF-8 codes from JSON file as Emoticons

Tags: json, utf-8

I am loading a JSON file that contains some UTF-8 codes, that represent emoticons.
The JSON content looks as follows:

```
"Studying! \uf4d6"
"Winning \uf40e\uf3c1 #4mile"
"Cheer me on \uf603 #werunamsterdam"
```

These UTF-8 codes are displayed as blocks in the browser. But when I look at this Unicode reference in Firefox, the codes are actually recognized!
(for example, UF4D6 is a book)

How do I convert the code from my json so that a browser can display them?

Comment: What does FF say about the encoding of your site? And what script language are you using? PHP?

Comment: Well, nothing. It just displays the code exactly like you see it here. (in other words, it just shows '\uf4d6' instead of an emoticon).
I probably don't use the right html tag?
<body>Testing my json content \uf4d6</body>

Comment: To display unicode characters in HTML, you have to escape them like this: &#xf4d6;

Comment: Thanks! That was part of the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code points from \uE000 to \uF8FF are in a private use area, so there aren't any standard glyphs associated with them.

You can, however, create your own font with suitable icons at these code points. This can be done quite easily using online tools like [IcoMoon](http://icomoon.io/). Alternatively, use a string replacement routine to swap these characters with suitable markup (e.g., replace `\uf4d6` with `<img src="/icons/book.png" alt="[Book]" />`)

Comment: Thanks! I still wonder why Firefox is able to display almost everything, see this page: http://apps.timwhitlock.info/emoji/tables/unicode

Answer (score 1):

These emoticons are encoded as regular characters as defined in Unicode, i.e. they're no different from the letter "A" or "%". All you need is a *font* that has glyphs for these "characters". Since not everyone can be expected to have such fonts installed (apparently you don't), if you want maximum compatibility, there are libraries for most languages that replace these characters with equivalent images. Google for one that suits your needs.

Comment: Thanks for the font tip, that might help to display characters that aren't supported by Arial. Firefox does this automatically it seems, because it shows almost every Emoticon, even when the font is set to Arial.
Still I'm confused about how to convert "\uf4d6" to the proper html tag. Right now the browser just shows "\uf4d6" exactly like that.